# QLineEdit сигналы

Tags: qt

Пишу:

```
QLineEdit * lineEdit = new QLineEdit(this);
connect(lineEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged()), this, SLOT(showAll()))
```

Слот `showAll` применяет ко всем остальным виджетам метод `->show();`, проблема в том, что не работает связка `connect`, ни при `twxtChanged` ни при `textEdited`, на вход сигналов подавал и `QString` как положено и ничего не подавал, все равно не работает. Вызванный отдельно от коннекта солт работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно так:

```
connect(lineEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString&)), this, SLOT(showAll()));
```

Comment: Спасибо, только не могу понять зачем писать именно Qstring&?

Comment: Сигнал - это обычная функция, которая может быть переопределена. Сигнатура сигнала при выполнении соединения должна быть сохранена.